# bin/sh: opt: command not found

Tags: git, sh, commit

When I use the command **git commit** I get the message **bin/sh: opt: command not found**. I am using OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 and I installed git using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). I also have XCODE, which I believe installs a lower version of git somewhere else, if that helps. When I do `which git` it responds with /usr/local/bin/git. I have used git before, but I never had this issue before. The strange part is that other git commands work like git clone, git status, and git pull as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `env GIT_TRACE=1 git commit`. I suspect you have set up a pre-commit or prepare-commit-message hook in this one particular repository, and it is trying to invoke some command called "opt".

Comment: This is the response:

env GIT_TRACE=1 git commit
09:49:24.402439 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'commit'
09:49:24.417260 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: '.git/hooks/pre-commit'
/bin/sh: opt: command not found

Comment: @torek, you are right. There is a ghook for pre commit in the project. 
`"ghooks": {
      "pre-commit": "opt --in pre-commit --exec \"npm run validate-webpack:dev\""
    }`
I removed this and all was fine. To fix the issue I installed a node package called [opt-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opt-cli) after adding the code back.

Answer (score 0):

@torek, you are right. There is a ghook for pre commit in the project. `"ghooks": { "pre-commit": "opt --in pre-commit --exec \"npm run validate-webpack:dev\"" }`
I removed this and all was fine. To fix the issue I installed a node package called [opt-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opt-cli) after adding the ghooks code back to the project.